# Where does `pub get` download pubspec dependencies to?

Tags: flutter, dart

In javascript, we have NPM and the `node_modules` folder in every project. I was not able to find a similar concept for Dart/ Flutter, except the `build` folder in my app, which contains a folder of a few dependencies I have in `pubspec.yaml`. It doesn't have any of the source code though, and I think it's actually built from something else. I've also looked in `/usr/local/flutter/packages` which is where my flutter is installed, but it only shows `flutter_driver`, `flutter_goldens`, and more seemingly unrelated folders.

I guess if wanted to read the source code, I really need to find the repo and read from that, or is there a location for dependencies I haven't looked?

---

I even found `projectDir/.dart_tool/pub`, which didn't have any of my packages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-get#the-system-package-cache):

> Dependencies downloaded over the internet, such as those from Git and
>   the pub.dev site, are stored in a system-wide cache. This means that
>   if multiple packages use the same version of the same dependency, it
>   only needs to be downloaded and stored locally once.
>
> By default, the system package cache is located in the `.pub-cache`
>   subdirectory of your home directory (on Mac and Linux), or in
>   `%APPDATA%\Pub\Cache` (on Windows; the location might vary depending on
>   the Windows version). You can configure the location of the cache by
>   setting the `PUB_CACHE` environment variable before running pub.

So for Mac and Linux for example, this would be `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org` by default.

Comment: Can I still edit these files, if I wanted to say, debug a known issue from a plugin? If this works, it will obviously affect all apps that depend on it.

Comment: It's possible but not recommended. I think changes will be overwritten when dependencies are upgraded, when the cache is cleared, etc. If the project is open sourced, it's better to take a copy of that repo (like a fork on GitHub) and change the dependency to a git dependency pointing to your fork, in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Is there a way to download the packages to flutter project (I'm using Android Studio) so I can jump to their declarations? Currently package classes etc show documents and can be used by if I try to jump to their declarations I get `Cannot find declaration to go to`

Answer (score 9):

### In Android Studio

I could directly view the source code of the package under `

> [External Libraries/Dart Packages/Your Packages]

[image]
`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using VScode you can find these dependencies under the dependencies window:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get pubspec downloaded from your flutter sdk location .

```
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
```

You can also clone package  git .

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Windows as your OS, you can find the packages under the folder that you installed your Flutter SDK to when setting up Android Studio.

In my case - using Windows 10 - the path is as follows, where `C:\` is my primary harddrive and `flutter\` the folder containing the Flutter SDK...

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\english_words-4.0.0
```

The above path for instance points to the "english words package", containing the most ~5000 used English words and some utility functions, which are mentioned and used in the Flutter tutorial on their official page for writing and running your first Flutter app.

https://pub.dev/packages/english_words

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed flutter using snap then the location might be

> /home/user/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that I've been command + clicking into these libraries all the time in VSCode.

However, it looks like packages are not stored in the app folder. Packages that we use in our projects are downloaded to `$FLUTTER_PATH/.pub-cache`, so if I'm looking for camera picker plugin, its in

```
/usr/local/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.5+2/lib/image_picker.dart
```