# Flutter: Using Visual Studio Code. Where is the shared preferences file?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how i can find the location and open the  shared preferences file that are used in my Flutter project.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628388/where-does-pub-get-download-pubspec-dependencies-to all packages are stored at %APPDATA%\Pub\Cache on windows

Comment: Hi Costa, thanks for your help. I asked wrong i think. What i mean is "Where are shared preferences stored?". I know that they are stored in a xml file, but what i need is to know where this xml file is.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored

Comment: Hi @Benyamin, yes this answer my question. What woulb be the path of the xml file if the Flutter App would be for Windows Desktop? Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure if it is stored on windows

Comment: In windows it as to be also stored somewhere. For example the counter example with shared preferences to make it persistence. It works on windows. There must be also some file to store the data on the Hard Drive.